# Autoincrement a meteor simpleschema member

Tags: mongodb, meteor, coffeescript

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
SimpleSchema.FaqSchema = new SimpleSchema
  order:
    type: Number
    autoValue: ->
      # somehow increment this by 1
  updatedAt:
    type: Date
    autoValue: ->
      new Date
  updatedBy:
    type: String
    autoValue: ->
      Meteor.userId()
  question: type: String
  answer: type: String
```

Unfortunately, there is nothing in Meteor documentation or simpleschema docs for this matter which explains how to do it. There is mongo docs here : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

However, this doesn't really help.

Any help is appreciated. The schema is in coffeescript but can be converted using http://js2.coffee/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a Meteor method on the server side that increments the order field by 1 during inserts. This method uses the [**meteor-mongo-counter**](https://github.com/awwx/meteor-mongo-counter) package which implements the "Counters Collection" technique described in the MongoDB documentation **[Create an Auto-Incrementing Sequence Field](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/)**:

**Server**

```
Meteor.methods
    "insertDocument": (doc) ->
        doc.order = incrementCounter "order"
        MyCollection.insert doc
        doc.order
```

**Client**

```
doc = 
    question: "Question 1"
    answer: "Answer 1"

# Instead of inserting with Collection.insert doc, use Meteor.call instead

Meteor.call "insertDocument", doc, (err, result) ->
    if result console.log "Inserted order number #{result}"
```

Comment: Didn't think of the atomic operation. Good find.